# How do I uninstall Kubuntu in elementary os?

Tags: updates, system, desktop

I just installed Kubuntu by installing sdmm and tasksel. Now I'm getting the kubuntu environment but getting a lot of junkware in application menu. I want to uninstall kubuntu so that I can enjoy my old one. I can see Kubuntu only on my lockscreen but not on desktop homescreen.

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo apt remove ________` (where the blank is the software that you installed)?

Comment: in ubuntu is  `sudo apt purge kubuntu-desktop` so if possible it is the same in EOs